# loop until list element N-1

Tags: python

Hey I just want to simple loop (for x in lists) so that it will loop until n-1 element in list?

I can check it using if or make new list without the last element, but the code become little unsimply, so do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate excluding the last element, like this

```
for item in my_list[:-1]:
```

This will actually create a new list, without the last element. So, the efficient way to do this would be to use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) like this

```
from itertools import islice
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for item in islice(my_list, len(my_list) - 1):
    print(item)
```

Comment: it is the same as "make new list without the last element" though